# how to Pass the elements in a structure to an unamed pipe?

Tags: c, ipc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>  

struct msg
{
    int pid;
    int giffs;
    int curr; 
};

main()
{
    struct msg send = {1, 2, 3};
    int p[2], pid, i;
    char inbuff[sizeof(send)];
    char *q;
    pipe(p);
    pid = fork();
    if(pid > 0)
    {
         write(p[1], (char *)&send, sizeof(send));
         printf("%ld \n", sizeof(send));
    }
    else
    { 
         read(p[0], inbuff, sizeof(send));
         printf("%s\n", inbuff);
    }
}
```

The problem is the elements in the structure are not appearing at the read end, 
could anyone please check on this. we can pass a string to a pipe, but I need to pass the bunch of integers to the pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>  
struct msg {
    int pid;
        int giffs;
        int curr;
};

main()
{

    struct msg send = {1, 2, 3};
    int p[2], pid, i;
    int *inbuff;
    char *q;
    pipe(p);
    pid= fork();
    if(pid > 0) {
            write(p[1], (char *)&send, sizeof(send));
            printf("%ld \n", sizeof(send));
            sleep(1);
    } else { 
        read(p[0],(char *) inbuff, sizeof(send));
    for (i=0;i<sizeof(send)/sizeof(int);i++){
            printf("%d\n", *inbuff++);
    }
    }
 }
```

try this code..........
here make sure you use waitpid() instead of sleep so that parent process waits for child procees to terminate or else you will get inappropriate response...........

Comment: I have used waitpid() in the parent process. But child process is printing garbage values. Could you please be specific where to use and how. And what is the function of waitpid(); Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: here what happens is you are making your child process to write and parent process to read from the pipe....
So before the child process writes anything your parent process tries to read from the pipe and hence it receives garbage value...
What you can do here is exchange your if and else statement blocks so that your child reads and parent writes and use sleep in child process this may solve your problem.



ps... the problem with waitpid() occurs as you mentioned i am trying to sort that out...

Comment: I like the way you explained. you are right the parent and child processes must be interchanged. It is working well now. Thank for your time chirag parekh.

Answer (score 1):

The bytes get read at the receiving end, but you try to print binary data as a string.

Treat the read bytes as `struct msg` instead:

```
else
{
     struct msg received; 
     read(p[0], &received, sizeof(received));
     printf("%d, %d, %d\n", received.pid, received.giffs, received.curr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Klas. It is working fine. I am concerned about large amount of data. if I send 100 elements. It may be difficult to print all the elements at the read end. I want to send the base address of the structure and at the read end I want to print all the elements.

Comment: Once you `fork`, the memory is no longer shared between parent and child (so the child cannot see changes made by the parent). If you want the child to be able to read the memory of the parent process you need to use either shared memory or threads.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time Klas. So it not possible by using pipes. I think pipes can be used to read the data from a write end b/w two related processes.

Comment: You can use a pipe to send data between processes. however, if you send a pointer that points to a string in the sending process, you cannot expect the reading process to find that string using a pointer sent through a pipe. The pointer has the same value as in the sending process, but the memory address pointed to wouldn't normally contain the same string, or even be readable by the receiving process.